# Spark NLP is not working in PySpark: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm trying to spark-submit a PySpark application but every time I try it throws this error when it tries to download a pre-trained model from Spark NLP:

`TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

Any idea what might be causing this?
Also, it's interesting to note that I've been practicing with these pre-trained pipelines in a jupyter notebook and it worked fine.

In case it's relevant, I'm using `Java 8`, `Spark 3.2.1`, `PySpark 3.2.1`, `Spark NLP 3.4.0` and `Python 3.10` (I've also tried with 3.9).

I'm also using a **pipenv environment**.

This is my spark session configuration:

```py
packages = ",".join(
    [
        "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1",
        "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.563",
        "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2",
        "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-api:3.2.2",
        "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-runtime:3.2.2",
        "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy:3.2.2",
        "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp-spark32_2.12:3.4.2",
        "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1",
    ]
)

# Starts spark session

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("twitter_app_nlp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages)
    .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
    .config(
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
        "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider",
    )
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 3)
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "8G")
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoDB)
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongoDB)
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

I've seen that installing the FAT jar inside the environment normally solves it. I did it and I added it to the spark session like this:

`.config('spark.jars.packages', '/Users/mac/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-uPYwcfrj/lib/spark-nlp-assembly-3.4.3.jar')`

But still doesn't work, I've also tried to post that path to the `.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath')` but no luck either.

I also tried using --packages in the command:

```
spark-submit main.py --files config.json \
     --packages com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp-spark_2.12:3.4.3
```

But didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The `spark-submit` command has the option `--packages` listing a remote library that I'm not sure is in the correct format.

Maybe try

```
export NLPJAR='/Users/mac/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-uPYwcfrj/lib/spark-nlp-assembly-3.4.3.jar'

spark-submit --jars $NLPJAR main.py
```

using **absolute path** or **file:/ URI** because directory expansion does not work with `--jars` (not sure if the order--options before application--is relevant) (see [Sumbitting Applications - Advanced Dependency Management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)).

If this works, it might be that Spark was not able to find the JARs in your *pipenv* environment, so it's necessary to configure the paths in the Spark configuration or use the `--driver-class-path` option

Note: changing [`spark.driver.extraClassPath`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) in the configuration will have no effect in client mode--and default `deploy-mode` is `client` (see [submitting applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)).

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work either